# How to convert value hex to float32 big endian in PyModbus

Tags: python, pymodbus

I'm currently coding modbus rtu in python using package pymodbus.
In this case, I will read the data from the TDS sensor using func code 4 / Read Input Registers (refer to the Aquas SMR-08 datasheet). The data was successfully obtained and I convert it to hex
, but the data must be converted again to the correct value. I try convert the hex value with scadacore (online hex converter) and I see the correct data on Float Big Endian (ABCD)

The Hex Value is 41FB:

[image: The Hex Value is 41FB]

conversion result is 31.375 (this is Temperature value):

[image: conversion result is 31.375 (this is Temperature value)]

So, how algorithm or what code pymodbus to convert like scadacore (online hexa conversion) ?

can anyone help ?
Thanks In Advance, and sorry for my bad english hihihi

this is my code

```
import time
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient
from pymodbus.constants import Defaults
from pymodbus.constants import Endian
from pymodbus.payload import BinaryPayloadDecoder
Defaults.RetryOnEmpty = True
Defaults.Timeout = 5
Defaults.Retries = 5

client = ModbusClient(method='rtu', port='/dev/ttyUSB0', timeout=2, stopbits=1, bytesize=8, 
parity='N', baudrate=19200)
client.connect()


while True:

tds1 = client.read_input_registers(address=0, count=2, unit=1)

bacatds1 = tds1.registers[0]
bacatds2 = tds1.registers[1]

tds1hex = hex(bacatds1)
tds2hex = hex(bacatds2)

print(tds1hex)
print(tds2hex)

decoder1 = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(tds1.registers, Endian.Little)
hasil1 = decoder1.decode_32bit_float()

print(hasil1)
print('==================================')
time.sleep(1)

# ----------------------------------------------------------------
tds2 = client.read_input_registers(address=1, count=2, unit=1)

bacatds3 = tds2.registers[0]
bacatds4 = tds2.registers[1]

tds3hex = hex(bacatds3)
tds4hex = hex(bacatds4)

print(tds3hex)
print(tds4hex)

decoder2 = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(tds2.registers, Endian.Big)
hasil2 = decoder2.decode_32bit_float()
print(hasil2)
print('===================================')
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Can you post a link to information about the Modbus registers of the sensor you are using?

Comment: there is the datasheet of SMR08, [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rbqKUdd5yacAh72zEwRshvUPkJzVTu8I/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

I went through a similar problem in converting the values fetched to a float value

Upon checking the internal code base for pymodbus

I came up with the below function

```
import struct

def decodeRegisters_float(in_registers,bit_size=32,step=2):

    n = len(in_registers)

    float_res = []
    for i in range(0,n,step):
        if bit_size == 32:
            pack_string = '!2H'
            unpack_string = '!f'
            raw = struct.pack(pack_string, in_registers[i] ,in_registers[i+1])
        elif bit_size == 64:
            pack_string = '!4H'
            unpack_string = '!d'
            raw = struct.pack(pack_string, in_registers[i] ,in_registers[i+1],in_registers[i+2],in_registers[i+3])
        value = struct.unpack(unpack_string, raw)[0]
        float_res += [value]

    return float_res
```

The arguments to the function are as below

`in_registers - Register values read from holding/input resistors`

`bit_size - 32,64`

`step - 2 for 32 and 4 for 64`

The above function can be considered as a wrapper once you have read the values and implicitly, need to convert them to the respective float values

Below is the example usage -

```
def _read_register_dtype_float(client,unit,nreg,registers=2,type='holding',bit_size=32,step=2):

        assert bit_size in [32,64],"Only 32 and 64 bit size is allowed to be read"

        if bit_size == 32:
            registers = nreg * registers
        elif bit_size == 64:
            registers = nreg * registers * 2
            step = 4

        if type == 'holding':
            res = client.read_holding_registers(0,registers,unit=unit)

        if type == 'input':
            res = client.read_input_registers(0,registers,unit=unit)

        return decodeRegisters_float(res.registers,bit_size=bit_size,step=step)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much knowledge about the python, But I have seen similar question in java.

I think you are not using the hex base.
I'm giving you the steps to achieve your requirement.

1. Consider your `hex` as an `string`.
2. convert `string` to `float` with the base 16.

After following these two steps you will get your output.

I'm providing you the link below for an example.

[Write hexadecimal values into register with leading zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64352018/write-hexadecimal-values-into-register-with-leading-zeros/64438627#64438627)

[Convert hex to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592158/convert-hex-to-float)

I hope, it would help you.